# How to find the eigenvalues of the operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Find the eigenvalues of the operator $(Ax)(t) = \frac{1}{t^\alpha} \int_{0}^{t} s^{\alpha - 1} x(s) \, ds$ , $Re\alpha>\frac{1}{p}$, in $L^p[0,1]$ space.

---

I tried $(A-\lambda I)x(t)=\frac{1}{t^\alpha} \int_{0}^{t} s^{\alpha - 1} x(s) \, ds-\lambda x(t)$ 
$\int_{0}^{t} s^{\alpha - 1} x(s) \, ds=\frac{1}{t^\alpha}(\alpha(t^\alpha x(t)-\int_{0}^{t} s^{\alpha - 1} x'(s) \, ds)$ 
Where $\int_{0}^{t} s^{\alpha - 1} x'(s) \, ds) = x(t)t^{\alpha-1}-\int_{0}^{t}(\alpha-1) s^{\alpha - 2} x(s) \, ds)$ 
Please explain how to solve this problem

Comment: I forgot about p. $1 \leq p < \infty$

Comment: The answer in the textbook is: let $a:=Re\alpha$, $Ax = \lambda x$, $\lambda=\sigma+i\tau$\
then eigenvalues fill the circle $(\sigma-\frac{1}{2}\frac{p}{pa-1})^2+\tau^2<\frac{p^2}{4(pa-1)^2})^2$ 
so I didn't get this solution

Answer (score 2):

You just need to multiply the equation $(A-\lambda I)x(t) = 0$ with $t^\alpha$ tp get
\begin{align}
\int_0^t s^{\alpha-1}x(s) ds = \lambda t^\alpha x(t).
\end{align}
Now differentiate to get
\begin{align}
t^{\alpha-1}x(t)= \lambda \alpha t^{\alpha-1} x(t) + \lambda t^{\alpha} x'(t).
\end{align}
This yields
\begin{align}
x'(t) = \frac{t^{\alpha-1}x(t) -\lambda \alpha t^{\alpha-1} x(t)}{ \lambda t^{\alpha}} =  \bigg(\frac{1}{\lambda} -\alpha \bigg)\frac{1}{t}x(t).
\end{align}
The solution to this is $x(t) = c t^{\frac{1}{\lambda} -\alpha}\in L^p([0,1])$. Thus, all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ are eigenvalues. It is straightforward to see that $\lambda = 0$ isnt an eigenvalue, because $Ax=0$ implies directly, that $x\equiv 0$ a.e. .

Comment: Sorry, I posted the answer from the textbook. Is it the same or not? I don't understand how to get the answer from the book